# MySQL copy value of field in one column to another field in the same column of table

Tags: mysql

I wish to copy the value of a field in a column to another field in the same column.  My reasoning is that field is ctrl-a delimited and I don't know how to input that using an insert manually.

I tried:

```
update table_foo
set my_column =
(
   select my_column
   from table_foo
   where id=5
)
where id=1;
```

this gives me:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table
```

Or if you know how to insert a CTRL+A delimited value as well that would solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual workaround for the "You can't specify target table" is to wrap it in yet another layer of subquery, which will cause MySQL to create a temporary table before running the UPDATE, rather than trying to read the table at the same time as updating it:

```
UPDATE table_foo
   SET my_column =
        ( SELECT my_column
            FROM ( SELECT my_column
                     FROM table_foo
                    WHERE id = 5
                 ) t
        )
 WHERE id = 1
;
```

That said, you say that your only issue is that you don't know how to enter Ctrl-A? That's much more easily solved. :-)   Use [the built-in `CHAR()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char). This:

```
UPDATE table_foo
   SET my_column = CONCAT(CHAR(1), 'text', CHAR(1))
 WHERE id = 1
;
```

will set `my_column` to `^Atext^A`.

(Disclaimer: these are both untested.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what "ctrl-a" delimited values are (in what character encoding?), but the following will do what you need, creating an entire table alias from which you can pull your selection:

`update table_foo set my_column = (SELECT my_column FROM (SELECT * FROM table_foo) AS t WHERE t.id = 5) where id=1`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html):

Error 1093 (ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED)
SQLSTATE = HY000
Message = "You can't specify target table 'x'
for update in FROM clause"
This error occurs in cases such as the following, which attempts to **modify a table and select from the same table in the subquery**:

```
UPDATE t1 SET column2 = (SELECT MAX(column1) FROM t1);
```

You can use a subquery for assignment within an UPDATE statement because subqueries are legal in UPDATE and DELETE statements as well as in SELECT statements. However, **you cannot use the same table** (in this case, table t1) for both the subquery FROM clause and the update target.

For a workaround read @spud and @ruakh answers.